# Machine Learning for repetitive form filling

Tags: machine-learning

I'm trying to use machine learning algorithms for repetitive form filling.
Here is a picture to illustrate that a little bit.

[image]

If you enter values in field A and B i would like to have a suggestion for field C. 
For this case i really would like to implement a Machine learning algorithm so that the system stays really flexible and only makes suggestions by the knowledge that was build.

I've already started reading programming collective intelligence and Artificial intelligence a modern approach. I also started to play around with Weka a little bit and found a pretty good [microsoft research paper on my problem](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/78662/alimeekpredictivemodelsofformfillingtechreport.pdf) too. But my main problem is that I can't really identify what algorithm group I should use. I'm primarily looking at Descision trees like C 4.5 but I'm not sure if this is the right way. Could you please give me any suggestions on my problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're starting out... good luck.

Go for a Huffman tree / Genetic algorithm randomizer... for a quick solution.

Go for implementing everything you can think of, then using an external efficacy classifier to figure out what to use for the next iteration, and randomize something along the way.... for the more complex solution.

Decision trees are incredibly inflexible when it comes to this type of stuff. Try fuzzy logic algorithms.